# Fading out removal of element from DOM with Stimulus

Tags: javascript, stimulusjs

I currently have this simple stimulus JS controller which removes an element from DOM

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"
export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [ "element" ]
    close () {
        this.elementTarget.remove()
    }
}
```

Is there a way to fade out the element before removal?

Answer (score 5):

I got something to kind of work with tailwind. I'll keep this till I find a more general solution

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"
export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [ "element" ]
    close () {
        this.element.classList.add('transform', 'opacity-0', 'transition', 'duration-1000');
        setTimeout(() => this.elementTarget.remove(), 1000)
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple solution that works fine.